# Vim Adventures- Level 7 - Stuck on: What's in a name

Tags: vim-adventures

This game is great, but I'm stuck on the What's in a name poem, and I don't want to give it away with my question, but I really need some help:

```
   What's in a na[m]e?
   That which we call
   a rose
   By any other name
-> would still smell as sweet.
```

[image]

The entrance to the puzzle is at the arrow going into the w in would.
The [m] in name is an un-passable block.
The a in name is the exit, moving upwards.

My key collection includes:

```
~   $%^   0
  wert
    dfghjkl;
 zx  b  ,
```

[image]

I think I can say the following without giving away any spoilers:

I can make it TO the a in name 5 different ways but I'm always missing that last turn to get off the platform.

I can get to the a with 0 turns left using my newest key: g or without it.
One way of me getting that far involves the $ key
I can't think of any ways that my other new keys: t f ; , can benefit me.

Comment: It's been a while, but I seem to recall going to the end of a long line then "skipping" up.  Like, say, getting to the `t` in `sweet` and then moving the cursor up to end up on the `l` in `call` or the `3` at the top. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 6):

I was **g**oin**g** **t**o **m**ention a hint, but that would **j**ust give it away.

(My problem was I hadn't figured out what to do with my spare key).

Comment: We don't want hints here.  We want answers.  Even if you are making it rather obvious with the bolded letters.

Comment: Can you give us the answer? This site is for answers, don't waste people's time please.

Answer (score 3):

l -> enter w

gg -> go to first line

tm -> go to a (on the left side of m)

k -> done

Comment: This is a pretty brief answer, do you think you could add some more context?

Comment: The context is in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

I actually used

- l
- gg
- $
- ; (since I used on another text `Fa`)
- k

But for sure the way using `tm` to get directly is more independent for this text working.

Comment: can you expand on how you were able to use `Fa`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have `g` key. It's obtained in the house where keys started to spread out.
2. In the paragraph starting `What's in a name?`, press `t` `m`. This is to register movement to put you before `m`.
3. Go out and reenter the paragraph.
4. Press: `gg` `;` `k`.
5. As you enter numeric expressions, press `%` `k`.